# Rounding TIME! to a number of days in Rebol

Tags: date, time, rebol, rebol3, rebol2

I've found one way to turn a TIME! in Rebol into a number of days: add it to a date and then subtract that same date.

```
>> dummy-date: 12-Dec-2012
== 12-Dec-2012

>> (dummy-date + 44835:11:58) - dummy-date
== 1868
```

That's...rather awkward.  Is there a better way built-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>> pick 44835:11:58 / 24 1
== 1868
```

or short

```
first  44835:11:58 / 24
```

Comment: **first 44835:11:58 / 24** appears to be the shortest approximation that exists at the moment.  I was asking because I wondered how easy it might be to get days if SUBTRACT on date returned a TIME!.  But it seems it doesn't because days is the lowest common denominator, since you might subtract two days without a time component.  :-/  It is still bad that DIFFERENCE is used to get a time difference, because all the other behaviors are related to [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be:

```
>> round/to 44835:11:58 / 24:00 1
== 1868
```

Answer (score 1):

```
time: 44835:11:58
round time/1 / 24
round first time / 24
```